# Problem with 'apply not defined' error in code creating a rotated oval shape (ellipse) in Python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Looking for Python code able to create a rotated ellipse (oval shape) on Pythons tkinter canvas I have found a solution online, but the final lines of the code:

```
dict = {}
dict['outline'] = 'black'
dict['fill']   = 'yellow'
dict['smooth'] = 'true'

# use a polygon to draw an oval rotated 30 degrees anti-clockwise
apply(canvas.create_polygon, tuple(poly_oval(40,40, 200,300, rotation=30)), dict)
```

raise when I run it in Python 3.11 ( the code is from year 2000 ) the error:

```
    apply(canvas.create_polygon, tuple(poly_oval(40,40, 200,300, rotation=30)), dict)
    ^^^^^
NameError: name 'apply' is not defined
```

What does the line of code giving the error do and how to rewrite it to make it run without an error?

The full code is available online [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-December/022013.html) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apply()` function can be found on 'Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk', 3rd edition, 2000, but to get the rotated oval you don't need it at all. So if you change:

```
apply(canvas.create_polygon, tuple(poly_oval(40,40, 200,300, rotation=30)), dict)
```

to:

```
canvas.create_polygon(poly_oval(40,40, 200,300, rotation=30), dict)
```

it will paint a nice rotated oval:

[image]

For the sake of completeness below the entire code:

```
import tkinter
import math
root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)

def poly_oval(x0,y0, x1,y1, steps=20, rotation=0):
    """return an oval as coordinates suitable for create_polygon"""

    # x0,y0,x1,y1 are as create_oval

    # rotation is in degrees anti-clockwise, convert to radians
    rotation = rotation * math.pi / 180.0

    # major and minor axes
    a = (x1 - x0) / 2.0
    b = (y1 - y0) / 2.0

    # center
    xc = x0 + a
    yc = y0 + b

    point_list = []

    # create the oval as a list of points
    for i in range(steps):

        # Calculate the angle for this step
        # 360 degrees == 2 pi radians
        theta = (math.pi * 2) * (float(i) / steps)

        x1 = a * math.cos(theta)
        y1 = b * math.sin(theta)

        # rotate x, y
        x = (x1 * math.cos(rotation)) + (y1 * math.sin(rotation))
        y = (y1 * math.cos(rotation)) - (x1 * math.sin(rotation))

        point_list.append(round(x + xc))
        point_list.append(round(y + yc))

    return point_list

dict = {}
dict['outline'] = 'black'
dict['fill']   = 'yellow'
dict['smooth'] = 'true'

# use a polygon to draw an oval rotated 30 degrees anti-clockwise
canvas.create_polygon(poly_oval(40,40, 200,300, rotation=30), dict)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252005/discussion-between-toyota-supra-and-claudio).